# Magento 2 : Extra fee not adding in Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, paypal-express, extrafee

I am trying to checkout with paypal express but it gives error of `PayPal gateway has rejected request`. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts". For solution I am adding `event.xml` and observer.

```
 <event name="payment_cart_collect_items_and_amounts">
        <observer name="paymentfee" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\AddCustomAmountItem" />
 </event>
```

**observer file execute function like**,

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();
        $customAmount = 100;
        $cart->addCustomItem(__('Custom Amount'), 1, 100);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method is proper but problem is just with amount mismatch. Amount must be same as the amount which is added in subtotal.